# How to print all symbols that a mach-o binary imports from dylibs?

Tags: macos, mach-o, otool

I am new to MacOS & MacOS programming. I would like to know how an application is working (by simply having a glimpse of the binary's imported system APIs for learning).

I tried otool, printed the help message, I saw the message says *-L prints the shared libraries used*. Then I ran `otool -L <binary-file>`, but it only printed the names of the used libraries, without any imported symbols.

Maybe I missed something in otool, or is there any other tool that can help get import symbols in a mach-o binary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get a simple list of imported symbols with `nm -u`:

```
% nm -u /bin/echo
___mb_cur_max
___stdoutp
_err
_exit
_fflush
_getenv
_mbtowc
_putchar
_putwchar
_strcmp
_strlen
dyld_stub_binder
```

For more detailed information, including the library that each symbol is expected to come from, you can use `dyldinfo`. This requires Xcode though, and has to be invoked as `xcrun dyldinfo`. You'll want the union of `-bind`, `-weak_bind` and `-lazy_bind`:

```
% xcrun dyldinfo -bind /bin/echo 
bind information:
segment section          address        type    addend dylib            symbol
__DATA_CONST __got            0x100004000    pointer      0 libSystem        ___mb_cur_max
__DATA_CONST __got            0x100004008    pointer      0 libSystem        ___stdoutp
__DATA_CONST __got            0x100004010    pointer      0 libSystem        dyld_stub_binder
% xcrun dyldinfo -weak_bind /bin/echo
no weak binding
% xcrun dyldinfo -lazy_bind /bin/echo
lazy binding information (from lazy_bind part of dyld info):
segment section          address    index  dylib            symbol
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008000 0x0000 libSystem        _err
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008008 0x000B libSystem        _exit
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008010 0x0017 libSystem        _fflush
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008018 0x0025 libSystem        _getenv
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008020 0x0033 libSystem        _mbtowc
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008028 0x0041 libSystem        _putchar
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008030 0x0050 libSystem        _putwchar
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008038 0x0060 libSystem        _strcmp
__DATA  __la_symbol_ptr  0x100008040 0x006E libSystem        _strlen
```

Comment: `nm -u -m /bin/echo` can be an easier way of seeing this information.

Comment: @bdash Thank you both for your helpful answers.